# dust.js server-side erroring with `undefined is not a function`

Tags: node.js, dust.js

I have what I thought was a fairly simple server-side dust template which I'm populating with data and passing to a mail service.

I compile the template at the top of my page with

```
var invite = fs.readFileSync('./views/mail/invite.dust', 'utf-8');
dust.compile(invite, 'invite');
```

then in my route I pass the data to the `dust.render` via

```
dust.render('invite', {link: link, email: email},
        function(err, html) {
        if (err) console.log('dust error', err, html);
        if (err) return next(err);
        mailObj.html = html;
        mailer(mailObj, next);
    });
```

In the console I get `dust error [TypeError: undefined is not a function] undefined`.

The dust.render method is expecting a function as far as I can tell. https://github.com/akdubya/dustjs/blob/master/lib/dust.js#L12

So what am I doing wrong here?

I've also added

```
var compiled = dust.compile(invite, 'invite');
dust.loadSource(compiled);
```

as per http://www.dustjs.com/guides/rendering/, but continue to get the same error

Comment: You're linking to the akdubya repo, which is years old-- what version of Dust are you running?

Comment: Oh, thanks. I'm running 2.6.2. I tried running 2.7.2 but got conflicts with 'engine-munger' which wants dustjs < 7.0.0

Comment: What does the compiled template look like? Does it exist at `dust.cache.invite` ?

Comment: putting `dust.cache.invite` to console returns a function with the definition `function body_0(chk,ctx){ return chk.w(" <... contents of dust file ...>");}`

Comment: That means that the loadSource is succeeding. Based on your answers and your passing note of engine-munger I'd say you have a Kraken or Adaro issue instead of a Dust issue. You might try logging `err.stack` to see where the exception is coming from. There's definitely a version of Adaro that supports Dust 2.7.1+, so try looking at that.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a solution to the problem, but turns out I didn't need to use dust directly. As @Interrobang mentioned, I am using Kraken. I was able to get the dust html from the dust template using

```
res.render('mail/invite', {link: link, email: email}, function(err, html) {
   //mailer here
});
```

I was expecting express to complain that headers were already sent, and didn't realize that if a function is supplied as a third argument, further processing of the html could happen.

All ended happily, if not unexpectedly.

Comment: My guess is that the version of Kraken you're using is one that forcefully clobbers private Dust methods, so Dust no longer works without Kraken. Using `res.render` allows you to use Dust-via-Kraken and is the correct approach in this case.